# How to launch an intent from a tapped AlertDialog shown on a map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-alertdialog, touch-event

I have implemented my own ItemizedOverlay class, and have populated a map with items. When an item (balloon) is tapped, my OntAp method launches an alertDialog with some information.

I am trying to achieve is this: when someone taps **that dialog**, a specific Intent is started. 
The problem is that I do not know how to "hear" a tap on that dialog. Its size is not fixed, nor is its location, and it also has no buttons.

This is the code for the onTap method within the ItemizedOverlay class:

```
    @Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    AlertDialog ad = dialog.create();
    ad.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    ad.show();
    return true;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what kind of listener to override and where? Do I have make my own custom AlertDialog implementation and how will that help resolve my problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own MyAlertDialog that extends AlertDialog and overrides dispatchTouchEvent() like this:

```
private class MyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog
{

    public MyAlertDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)
    {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        this.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the place you call Builder, do the following:

```
      mDialog = new MyAlertDialog(mContext);
      mDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.poi);
      mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
      mDialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      mDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find an answer for this so I used a workaround and added a button with a listener on it. However, this will not do for the final solution, it is just for testing purposes. Still looking for a solution...